# Want a function to add an images source property to a larger image

Tags: javascript, image, function

I want to create a function so when you press on one of the 5 or more available images another image will gain and source of the one you clicked on. This is so when you click on an image, a frame will open up and display a larger size of that image.

This is the small image code:

```
<img src="Media//Gallery//img_1.jpg" onclick="showLarge();" alt="Gallery Image 1" />
```

And this is the blank space for the other image which needs to gain the source of the small image for it to be displayed:

```
<img name="largeImage" src="Media//Gallery//Image_1.jpg" alt="Large Image" />
```

This is my JavaScript Function so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLarge() {
    var largeFrame = document.getElementById("zoomedIn");
    largeFrame.style.visibility='visible';
    }
</script>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="Media//Gallery//img_1.jpg" onclick="showLarge(this);" alt="Gallery Image 1" />
<script>
function showLarge(img)
{
    var largeFrame = document.getElementById("zoomedIn");
    largeFrame.style.visibility='visible';
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('ID_OF_LARGE_IMAGE');
    largeImage.src = img.src;
}
</script>
```

i think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="URL_TO_BIG_IMAGE" class="preview">
   <img src="URL_TO_SMALL_IMAGE" alt="Gallery Image 1" />
</a>

<div class="view">
   <img hidden="hidden" id="big"/>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
   for (var elem in document.getElementsByClassName('preview')){
       elem.onclick = function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           document.getElementById('big')
               .setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('href'))
               .setAttribute('hidden', false);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely helpful but I am not sure I need the window.onload because of how the page works. Might try experimenting with it though!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your friend :)

add a class to your small image first.

```
$('.smallImage').click( function() {
  var imageSource = $(this).attr('src');
  // do things like enlarging, changing image source to a bigger image etc
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not know jQuery as of now since I am still trying to learn JavaScript but will look into it!